# Find HTML text that isn't saved as a value?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm inspecting a website field where I can enter text. On most text boxes/fields, when you enter text, it will be saved as 'innerText' or as a value 'text', but this field doesn't save the string like that anywhere in html. This means I can't edit the text that is in that field.

Where would this string be stored, and how could I edit it using javascript?

```
<div id="mirror" class="mirror-text style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea" aria-hidden="false">sdslll&nbsp;</div>


<div class="textarea-container fit style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea">
  <textarea id="textarea" class="style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea" rows="3" autocomplete="off" required="" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
</div>
```

As you can see, "mirror" holds the text I want to edit. But when I edit that, it doesn't take effect

Comment: Can you post your HTML and JS please which you have written please?

Comment: not possible to come to a conclusion unless the code is seen. But assuming it will a localStorgae. Also check if there is any network call

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
    <input id='in' type='text' />
    <h3 id='out'></h3>
    <script>
        let input = document.getElementById('in');
        let output = document.getElementById('out');

        document.onkeyup = function () {
            output.innerHTML = input.value;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The text still stays the same on screen

Comment: Nothing changes when you type something into the text field?

Comment: That's the thing, only the text changes in the field and in the element when you manually enter the keys

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () { setValue(); }

    function setValue(){
        document.getElementById("mirror").value = "Some value here";
    }
</script>


<input id="mirror" class="mirror-text style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea" aria-hidden="false" value="sdslll&nbsp;">

<div class="textarea-container fit style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea">
    <textarea id="textarea" class="style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea" rows="3" autocomplete="off" required="" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: See, when I edit this element at all, it doesn't take affect. The text is still the same. Like the element changes in the source. But on screen, the text is the same

Comment: You cannot edit a `div` element. You can see my updated code. I have replaced the div element with input element and on page load, I update the value of the input element.

Comment: Hmm, the HTML code is changing, but text on screen is still the same